# Can airpod with wrong spelling on the case be original?

Tags: airpods

Can an original Apple AirPod have wrong spelling on the charging case and airpod labels?

A friend just bought new, never opened airpods on a P2P marketplace. Upon receiving them and checking for whether they were fake everything looked fine except that there is misspelling on the labels on the charging case and airpods.

[image]

[image]

You can see on the charging case that almost all words are misspelled, notably Apple spelled Apoie, and then the airpod seems to say the same.

I thought this would immediately mean they are fake, however I looked up the serial number on the inside of the charger and tested it on checkcoverage.apple.com and it shows as valid.

I also connected it to an iphone and it connected with no issues just as an original AirPod would.

[image]

So I am at a loss. Find it hard to believe that original Apple products could have these errors, but I also expected a fake product to not have a valid serial number and for the iphone to recognize it as a non airpod.

Comment: Why?  Serial numbers have rules, throw dice, pick random numbers, hit one that works in the system.  They're fake.

Comment: Ok, I get the part of random serial numbers, but could a fake be picked up by iOS as airpods?

Comment: Most likely, all of the fakes have a valid serial number. *The same serial number*.

Comment: A way to tell if they were fakes without looking at the serial number, and before they were purchased, is the price.

Comment: It’s not that unusual to see people selling unopened gifts they can’t return at a discount. So sure ridiculous discounts are a clear tell, but reasonable discounts don’t signal fake as clearly. By the way, I’m not the buyer so while the tone is amusing I’m more interested in the technical details.

Comment: Don't buy from "P2P marketplaces"....

Comment: What will you pay for 100 identical ones? :-).

Comment: Why aren't the answers covering the second part of the question, why doesn't the iphone detect these as no-airpods? Or are all fake airpods detected as genuine when connecting with iphone?

Answer (score 66):

Of course these are fake. Or perhaps, more accurate, counterfeit. I think it’s safe to say, a genuine Apple product will not have a spelling typo.

Comment: If you have a genuine Apple product with a typo, you could sell it for 10x to way more to a collector. The most likely answer is total knock off...

Comment: Better still - has there ever been a documented instance of a true Apple typo?

Comment: This is not a "typo". It's an intentional avoidance of trademarks and keywords in (probably misguided) hopes of avoiding the counterfeits being intercepted by customs or prosecuted.

Comment: Of course. But if Apple did it, it would in fact, be a typo. Right?

Comment: *One* typo on a product, maybe in a pre-production sample, perhaps. At least twelve and with such poor printing? No.

Comment: Ok, no doubt it’s counterfeit. Still curious how the iPhone recognizes the device as an AirPod. I would expect if not made by Apple they wouldn’t have the software to be recognized as AirPods as shown in the third image. Is the software also replicable/copied in a way it mimics the originals?

Comment: @twalbaum presumably yes. It's not always easy to read and copy a device's firmware, but it's always possible if you're determined enough.

Comment: AirPods aren’t really made by Apple.  They are made in China to Apple’s design (which is fully disclosed with better spelling).  These work because they are made to the same design _except_ for the spelling.

Comment: @R.. Thay ure elso clevarly evoiding lhe capywrite af Deslinad Colifornia ond Assemblod.

Comment: @JustinLardinois You don't have to copy the firmware, you just have to give valid responses to the iphones requests. Depending on encryption this is way easier than copying the firmware.

Comment: @xyious which would be implementing new firmware as a drop-in replacement for the original. Either way, I was answering the question of whether firmware could be copied or not.

Answer (score 20):

They cribbed the serial number off an actual pair of AirPods which the counterfeiter probably saw at an Apple store.  If you had bought two, you would notice the same serial number on both.

The counterfeiters easily could have done a better job. It's their version of open disclosure: they're *not even trying to hide* that these are knockoffs.  In the same way that many scammers claim to be from Nigeria because they find it profitable to warn off the savvy, leaving only the gullible.  Or in this case, the illiterate.

Comment: Plus, they're not in violation of the "Apple" trademark, because Apoie.

Comment: @Alexander They likely are in violation of the trademark, though this can be decided only by a judge. The purpose of trademark law is to avoid confusion between similar goods from different companies, and whether this confusion was well avoided will be taken into account when considering whether or not there was a trademark violation. Similar design and spelling, with only subtle differences, will tend to be judged as contributing to confusion between the products, and thus trademark violation.

Comment: Also, you can only sue them in *Colifornia*