# Have there been any documented typos on genuine Apple products?

Tags: history, hardware

The comment chain under an answer on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376404/can-airpod-with-wrong-spelling-on-the-case-be-original) question brought up an interesting question.  Have there been any documented typos or production mistakes on genuine Apple products released into the wild?

Comment: While the question is admittedly intriguing, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't follow the guidelines [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I agree with @IconDaemon. Intriguing, but not within the scope of the Help file.

Comment: Of course, typos like this always happen. I once saw a typo in the Hungarian translation of macOS 10.7 Lion. (System Preferences/Desktop & Screen Saver/Screen Saver: the Preview option was translated as "Tesztelelés" instead of "Tesztelés"). Of course, a typo like this on a physical product would be a bigger disaster, since it's not that easy to get rid of it.

Comment: @TamásSengel I am specifically asking about hardware products and not software.

Comment: I disagree that it's off-topic and don't see what guidelines it violates. This is practical (the knowledge can help weigh the importantance of typos when guessing if a product is fake), easily answerable without opinion (by providing examples of typos), reasonably scoped (a typo example is quite narrow), and doesn't lead to discussion more than any other factual answer.

Comment: Can the moderator who closed the question please explain?  I’m not familiar with all of the subtleties of this particular site yet so I would like to know why exactly this *isn’t* on topic.

Comment: This question falls under the “no actual problem to be solved” category (3rd bullet point on first link).  Additionally, it’s a bit far fetched to assume a *marketing* savvy company like Apple would allow their logo and trademarked slogans to have typos.   I can tell you from first hand experience, those things are supplied as graphic files from Apple and not created individually as they are manufactured